# Pyinstaller Placing Images On Separate File Problem? How Do I Fix This?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pyinstaller

I am trying to place my images on a seperate file then my  exe BECAUSE ***I have alot of images and I dont want the person scrolling throw thousands of images just to find the exe***

> I dont know if I am missing something on my .spec

this is what I did I made a folder for my images and added them and then the exe is outside my image folders but whats happening is its not detecting the images on that folder ***am I messing something on my .spec file?**

[image]

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['tower.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Habib\\Desktop\\AllMyGames\\TowerD'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=['C:\Users\Habib\Desktop\AllMyGames\TowerD\dist\image'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='tower',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False )
```

it will end up just saying

```
FAILED TO EXECUTE SCRIPT
```

Comment: Two things: 1. If you have a new question, you should create a new question rather than edit an old one (and if you don't think the old question is worthwhile for other people, you can delete it). 2. This seems a bit trivial to put such a large bounty on.

Comment: Your question does not provide enough details for us to accurately reproduce your problem. Please update your question to include the exact folder structure and commands you are using before you get this error.

Comment: Your spec file works fine for me, through `pyinstaller tower.spec` and then running `dist/tower`. So if it's not working for you, you'll have to provide more details for us to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Multihunter said that the path is not escaped so the script is failing, here is the simplest solution to it

replace

```py
datas=['C:\Users\Habib\Desktop\AllMyGames\TowerD\dist\image']
```

with

```py
datas=[r'C:\Users\Habib\Desktop\AllMyGames\TowerD\dist\image']
```

prepending the `r` to your string will not escape any characters and your path will be as you wanted it to be.

See [this](https://www.journaldev.com/23598/python-raw-string) for reference

Answer (score 3):

Two problems I see:

1. Your `datas` string contain backslashes (escape character for python strings), resulting in an invalid string for a path.
2. The `datas` property is incorrectly structured.

From the docs:

> The list of data files is a list of tuples. Each tuple has two values, both of which must be strings:
>
> - The first string specifies the file or files as they are in this system now.
> - The second specifies the name of the folder to contain the files at run-time.

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files

So, assuming your project root is `C:\Users\Habib\Desktop\AllMyGames\TowerD`, change

```py
# Change this line
datas=['C:\Users\Habib\Desktop\AllMyGames\TowerD\dist\image']
# To this
datas=[('dist/image', 'image')]
```

And I think it will work.

Comment: is there like a update command that I can put in the cmd because the problem is still there and says "failed to execute script"

Comment: What command, exactly, are you trying to run?

Comment: I am trying to run the exe of my game

Answer (score -1):

I would recomend you to check if your image is in ico format, if it isnt
use :https://icoconvert.com
If this still does not work re do the procces but in your cmd promp write 'pyinstaller -icon "Your .ico file" and your project.py'